# How can drag and drop two events in between the dates?

Tags: angular

**HTML CODE**
This is my html code for a fullcalendar

```
         <div class='app'>
       <div class='app-calendar' *ngIf="calendarVisible">
        <full-calendar
              #calendar
              defaultView="dayGridMonth"
              [header]="{
             left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
              }"
              [plugins]="calendarPlugins"
              [weekends]="calendarWeekends"
              [events]="calendarEvents"
            (dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"
            ></full-calendar>
         </div>
        </div>
```

---

**Component class**

```
            export class AppComponent {


            @ViewChild('calendar') calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; // the #calendar in the 
         template


                   handleDateClick(arg) {
            if (confirm('Would you like to add an event to ' + arg.dateStr + ' ?')) {
                this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents.concat({ // add new event data. must create 
            new array
                 title: 'New Event',
                 start: arg.date,
                allDay: arg.allDay
               })
             }
           }

           }
```

I want to drag and event from one date to another date.

Comment: just try to use `[editable]="true"` in your html. it will allow you to drag and drop event between dates.

Comment: Thank you .it works for me ., But when click on another date and add new event ,the previous event will back to the date where its created first

Comment: yes and the reason is `calendarEvents` is not updated yet after drag and drop. so you need to update your `calendarEvents` array after drop event.

Comment: How can i update the calendarEvents ?

Comment: i have created a little example about how you can handle drag and drop event. please see this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-yzjckq)

Comment: thank you ,it would be very helpful

Comment: i have another one doubt, that is how can edit events when i click on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209299/discussion-between-farhat-zaman-and-codeigniter).